# Why is this html error being rendered in my POST?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an availability calendar that I'm trying to POST to my database using Laravel. When i dump out my POST I get this..

```
string(1440) "s:1430:"2012-11-06;;1;;888,2012-11-07;;1;;888,2012-11-08;;
1;;888,2012-11-09;;1;;888,2012-11-10;;1;;888,2012-11-11;;1;;888,2012-11-12;;
1;;888,2012-11 13;;1;;888,2012-11-14;;1;;888,2012-11-15;;1;;888,2012-11-16;;1;;
888,2012-11-17;;1;;888,2012-11-18;;1;;888,2012-11-19;;1;;888,2012-11-20;;1;;888,
2012-11-21;;1;;888,2012-11-22;;1;;888,2012-11-23;;1;;888,2012-11-24;;1;;888,
2012-11-25;;1;;888,2012-11-26;;1;;888,2012-11-27;;1;;888,2012-11-28;;2;;0,array(1)
{["availability"]=>string(973) "s:964:"2012-11-05;;1;;888,2012-11-29;;1;;
888,2012-11-30;;1;;888,array(1) {["availability"]=>string(12) "availability"}

<html><h2>Unhandled Exception</h2><h3>Message:</h3><pre>Error rendering view:   
[layouts.admin] Undefined variable: title</pre><h3>Location:</h3>               
<pre>/Users/corymjacik/Sites/shipwatch_v2.1/storage/views/33f72cb6519c7f146dc8d6af4b948300 on line 5</pre><h3>Stack Trace:</h3>
<pre>#0 /Users/corymjacik/Sites/shipwatch_v2.1/laravel/laravel.php(40): 
Laravel\Error::native(8";"}  
<html><h2>Unhandled Exception</h2><h3>Message:</h3> 
<pre>Error rendering view: [layouts.admin]Undefined variable: title</pre> 
<h3>Location:</h3>
              <pre>/Users/corymjacik/Sites/shipwatch_v2.1/storage/views/33f72cb6519c7f146dc8d6af4b948300 
on line 5</pre><h3>Stack Trace:</h3> <pre>#0 /Users/corymjacik/Sites/shipwatch_v2.1/laravel/laravel.php(40): 
Laravel\Error::native(8";"
```

What might be causing this error, and why is it being included in my POST to the database? Below is my controller code. Everything works just fine, like this. I'm able to post that string to the database (which I turned into a string from an array using serialize()) and I'm also able to get it from the database and it displays on the frontend just fine. The errors don't seem to make a difference, but I just feel like I'm doing something slightly wrong.

```
public function post_availability_save()
  {
$availability = serialize(Input::get('dop_booking_calendar'));
//var_dump($availability);die;

$id = Auth::user()->id;

Availability::update($id, array(
  'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
  'availability' => $availability
  ));
return Redirect::to('admin');
}

  public function get_availability_load()
  {
$id = Auth::user()->id;

$availability = array(
  'availability' => Availability::find($id)->availability
);

var_dump($availability);

}
```

**EDIT**
Messing around with it a bit more, it is also dumping out the beginning of my html layout...
Anyone know what causes this? I'll dig a bit deeper.
***EDIT*** 11/13/12

```
//*This is what ends up in my database (Type:TEXT) //
,2012-11-13;;1;;1,2012-11-14;;1;;1,2012-11-15;;1;;1,2012-11-16;;1;;1,2012-11- 
17;;1;;1,2012-11-18;;1;;1,2012-11-19;;1;;1,2012-11-20;;1;;1,2012-11-21;;1;;1,2012
-11-22;;1;;1,2012-11-23;;1;;1,2012-11-24;;1;;1,2012-11-25;;1;;1,2012-11-26;;1;;1,
2012-11-27;;1;;1,2012-11-28;;1;;1,Array
(
    [availability] => 1
)
<html><h2>Unhandled Exception</h2>
<h3>Message:</h3>
<pre>Error rendering view: [layouts.admin] Undefined variable: title</pre>
<h3>Location:</h3>
             <pre>/Users/cory/Sites/shipwatchpoint_v2.1/storage/views/e2b30637bfaa9d210e31baf35870d230 on line 5</pre>
<h3>Stack Trace:</h3>
<pre>#0 /Users/corymjacik/Sites/shipwatchpoint_v2.1/laravel/laravel.php(40): Laravel\Error::native(8

// *layouts.admin.blade.php //
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- CSS -->
    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/jquery.dop.BookingCalendar.css') }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/app.css') }}

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/ico/favicon.ico">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      {{ $content }}
    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    {{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/app.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.dop.BookingCalendar.js') }}

  </body>
</html>

//*admin controller (public restful is set to true)//
public function get_index()
  {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $unit = array(
      'unit' => Unit::find($id),
      'unit_admin' => Unit::find($id)->user,
      //'availability' => Availability::all() added this and it still showed errors
    );

    //var_dump($unit);die;

    $this->layout->title = 'Admin Profile';
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'admin.index', $unit);
  }

public function post_availability_save()
  {
    //$availability = serialize(Input::get('dop_booking_calendar'));
    $availability = Input::get('dop_booking_calendar');
    //var_dump($availability);die;

    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    Availability::update($id, array(
      'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
      'availability' => $availability
      ));
    return Redirect::to('admin');
  }

  public function get_availability_load()
  {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $availability = array(
      'availability' => Availability::find($id)->availability
    );

    var_dump($availability);

  }
```

Comment: I'm using the most recent, 3.2.11

Comment: The undefined variables are all defined. I'm thinking it might be a controller issue and I would have to redirect to my 'admin' controller, however, I tried that and it still isn't working. Also, in order show the availability in the frontend, the only way I could figure out how to do it was to var_dump my get request. Not sure if this method is correct either...

Comment: Sorry, the most recent version of Laravel

Comment: Do you ever pass a title to the layout? http://laravel.com/docs/views#binding-data-to-views

Comment: I'm passing my title to the layout in a different controller action. I  think I may have found a solution but I still need to troubleshoot it a bit more. I'm using a plugin, that is making an AJAX call to the specified controller to do the post, I think I may have to return something or redirect to my 'admin' controller where I am passing the title and content to the view.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end @coryjacik?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Still getting the errors.

Comment: Can you post your "layouts.admin" view code? it should be under views directory. Also, it seems that your controller is RESTful, so did you set the variable **public $restful = true;**?

Comment: @iTech yes public $restful is set to true. And other than the error showing up in the database after the data, everything works fine on the frontend this way. The availability calendar saves the correct days, and loads them correctly. The error only shows up under the Network tab when viewing the 'get' call. Nothing on the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. So, I finally figured it out. The error was being sent through in the post because I was var_dump'ing the results that we're being selected. I fixed it by 'die' and 'json_encode'. 
Thanks to everyone that helped!

Answer (score 3):

```
return Redirect::to('admin');
```

To send over the 'title' in $title or set it in the layout just like you did in the action_index()

```
return Redirect::to('admin')->with('title','supercooltitle');
```

or

```
return Redirect::to('admin')->with_title('supercooltitle');
```

Then your view can grab $title and quit showing that undefined reference.

Other options would be setting it on the layout similar to what you've done with the index.

Comment: hey, thanks for answering...this didn't work..narrowed it down even further though...seems like when I get the data initially with $availability = serialize(Input::get('dop_booking_calendar')); or even $availability = Input::get('dop_booking_calendar'); ..the errors are already being dumped in that data..so redirecting doesn't work because it is happening after the error has already been posted.

Comment: I don't understand I'm afraid.  When you dd($availability); you have an error stored in the Input?  Or it's throwing the exception stating there isn't a $title variable?  Was that not the original problem?  I'd like to help here.

Comment: the error gets stored in the POST data. so when i get the data from the form and submit it to the database, that's the only indication that there was an error, other than that everything is working perfectly fine. So $_POST['dopbookingcalendar'] returns the error. There is a huge javascript file setting all of these variables, there must be something going on with that, I haven't had the time to troubleshoot that file yet though